# How to create a browse button to select a folder in tcl/tk

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

How can I select a folder/file using a browse button. I want to know just what to put in the -command of the button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To ask the user to choose a file to open, you call `tk_getOpenFile`. That invokes the system dialog box on some platforms, and an internally-defined dialog on others. It returns the fully-qualified filename. (There's also `tk_getSaveFile` for when you're doing a *Save As…* action.)

The equivalent for selecting a directory is `tk_chooseDirectory`.

Here's an example of using it:

```
button .b -text "Click me!" -command {
    set theFile [tk_getOpenFile]
    puts "You chose $theFile"
}
pack .b
```

However, for anything much more complicated than that, *lots* of community experience says that it is easier to create a helper procedure and put a call to that in the `-command` option. It's not that you *must* do so, but it is quicker to code and less error-prone. Easier to test as well.

Comment: with this code I'm able to select a file but unable to select a folder. Can you please tell me what to do if I want to select a folder? @Donalfellows